# Pandas not found, although installed via Anaconda and seeming to work in debug console

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda, python-import

I have created a conda environment to manipulate existing excel files using the pandas library. Unfortunately, already the first line of code is giving me a headache:

> When I import pandas via `import pandas as pd`  I get the following error message:
> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`. I get the same error message when I execute my python file using the conda base environment.

I have already searched the web for half a day, reading articles that more or less all say the same thing: if you get this error message, it means that pandas is not installed properly in your environment. However, I have already checked this multiple times for both my custom conda environment as well as for the base environment and pandas is definitely installed. **Moreover, when I enter debug mode, the pd.read_excel() function does work and returns a printable data frame...**

I would be really grateful for any help/suggestions!!!

*N.B. I'm using studio code on an M1 Mac.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS Code make sure the right python interpreter is selected, it should be from your conda env you have defined (this helps with the linting, if pandas not found it will highlight the import pandas line)

```
Shift + Cmd + P > Python: Select Interpreter
```

Then, in terminal check you are using python from the conda environment you have created

```
where python
```

If all is fine and it's still not working, then re-create conda environment as follows -

```
conda create --name pandas_env --python=3.8 pip
conda activate pandas_env
pip install pandas
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! May I ask what the word `pip` after `--python=3.8` means? And do you think that using python 3.8 will resolve the issue? I have just tried to run my code with PyCharm and strangely with this IDE it all works. So it seems to be an issue specific to Studio Code (where I have double-checked that I am using the correct python interpreter from my environment by the way).

Comment: With one of the conda version I had this issue where the conda environment would use the system pip to install pip packages instead of the environment specific pip and this was the solution to that. Since your problem sounded similar I thought that would help. Python 3.8 was just an example, you can use any version and it should work fine as long as you install pip while creating conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **venv**. It is a standard python library to create lightweight environments.

To use you can do:

```
python3 -m venv my_environment
source my_environment/bin/activate
pip install pandas
```

Then you can try and run your program to see if this would work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'd rather work with conda environments, though.